# How to enable textbox on checkbox.checked on C#?

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm new to C#. The textbox1 is locked by default and I want to enable it the moment I check the checkbox1. I use the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
private void checkboxevent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked = true)
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
    else
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Winforms, WPF, Asp.NET or?

Comment: Cannot be WPF, in WPF it would be `IsChecked`.

Comment: checkBox1.Checked = textBox1.Enabled;

Comment: Winforms. checkBox1.Checked = textBox1.Enabled doesn't work too.

Answer (score 10):

`=` is the assignment operator
`==` is the equality operator

Take a close look at the following statement

```
if (checkBox1.Checked = true)
```

Comment: Are you sure the event handler is getting called?

Comment: Probably not. When I put this code under a buttonclick, works fine. But I need to make it work at the moment the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Have you tried adding the eventhandler to the `CheckStateChanged` event of your checkbox?

Comment: No problem. Feel free to click the checkmark to indicate that this is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

add `autopostaback="true"` for your `checkbox` in order to refresh the page whenever the checkbox is checked or unchecked

I'm assuming that you're talking about webforms.

Also `= true` is incorrect. It should be `== true`

Also, `== true` is altogether redundant. `if (checkbox.Checked)` is all you need.

Comment: Could be WinForms, and they don't have AutoPostBack. :)

Comment: Yeah, and if it's Webforms, do you really wanna post back just to enable a text box. Better to use some jQuery

Comment: Agreed, but I am attempting to answer the question rather than propose a different approach.